# Send url of a page to another

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a SQL command that returns the full value of the URL of the page it is :
`[##cms.request.rawurl##]` that returns the full URL.
I'd send this address for sending to another page and load in a div called: load-fac and I wrote the blow code but it is not working :
my URL is : `reservation/oneway/list.bc?bcpage=12&page=1&cat=130`

and here is my code:

```
<script>
var url= $('[##cms.request.rawurl##]');
$('.load-face').load('/one-wayajax.bc?url='+url")
</script>
```

Comment: Print the `url` and Check your console for better clearance...

Comment: just check the console and let us know the error you are getting. I think you have given one extra ' " ' at the end of the load method. just remove it and check it again.

Answer (score 4):

You have a typo:

```
$('.load-face').load('/one-wayajax.bc?url='+url")
                                               ▲
```

Should be:

```
$('.load-face').load('/one-wayajax.bc?url='+url);
```

Comment: it's not work for me..and send nothing to my next page

Comment: What do you get when you do `console.log(url);`?

Comment: So What you're saying is that `$('[##cms.request.rawurl##]')` doesn't return **anything** ?

Comment: when i use of [##cms.request.rawurl##] separately it is work correctly. but in this function it is not working and my second page not load.

Comment: Doesn't make sense. If  `$('[##cms.request.rawurl##]')` works OK, then the `url` variable should have a value! Let me ask again: What do you get when you do `console.log(url);`? Do you know how to use `console.log`?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/150682/discussion-between-koby-douek-and-inaz).